# Customize tooltips in Blazorise Charts or how to setup callbacks in object, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js, blazorise

I'm trying to customize chart tooltip text with Blazorise.Charts which is based on [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html).
I know how to do this with JS:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(context) {
                    
                    return ..;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve the same with C#:

```
 <LineChart @ref="LineChart" TItem="long" id="@ChartId" Class="mw-100" OptionsObject="GetOptionsObject()"/>

private object GetOptionsObject()
{
    return new
    {
        Plugins = new 
        {
           Tooltips = new{
                Padding = 10,
                UsePointStyle = true,
                Position = "nearest",
                XAlign = "center",
                YAlign = "bottom",
                Callbacks = new {
                   Label = ...// stuck here
                }
            }
        }            
}
```

Can i define some delegate function and would it work with the object? Is there some other way to manage tooltips in Blazorise Charts?

Comment: I don't know Blazorise but having a look to the code, "callbacks" node doesn't seem supported https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/blob/master/Source/Extensions/Blazorise.Charts/Options/ChartTooltips.cs

Comment: yea, but you can pass the options object, with no types in it. Is it possible to make callbacks inside the object?

Comment: Probably you have already seen : https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/313